# Why Euler equation holds for any asset i and t

Tags: gmm

Intuitively the Euler equation sets the marginal loss in utility from saving an additional unit of wealth in the current period equal to the marginal gain in expected discounted utility from consuming the resulting savings in the next period. If the Euler equation did not hold for some asset, then the consumer would have an incentive either to invest more in that asset or to invest less in the asset and possibly sell it short. Hence, the Euler equation needs to hold for every asset in equilibrium.

But I am not sure how to explain this method with the Euler equation itself?

The equation:
$$E\left[\beta(\frac{ C_{t+1} }{C_{t}})^{γ−1}(R_{it} + 1)\right] = 1$$

Comment: Are you asking for the mathematical derivation?

Comment: yes mate. For E[β(Ct+1/Ct)^ (γ -1) (Rit+1)] = 1.

Comment: Seems like you have a definite function $U(C_t)$ in mind. What is it?

Comment: Appreciated your time. My question is actually like this: For any asset i with return Rit from period t to t + 1, the representative agent with utility function $$U(C) = \sum\limits_{q=0}^∞ \beta^q C_q^γ$$ can choose to determine the optimal consumption path C0, C1....β E (0; 1) is the discount factor and γ > 0 is the risk aversion parameter.

Comment: 1. Prove the Equation hold for any asset i and t.  - I know how to proof it by words but not sure how to show it by taking derivative of U.

Comment: 2. With data Rit, i = 1 ... 2 to k, t = 1, 2 d... to T what moment conditions
can be gotten out of this equations?

Comment: Why is this tagged with [tag:gmm]?